# How to unregister an NSNotification in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have two controllers

```
class CtrlA: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(CtrlB.self, selector: #selector(CtrlB.badge(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(CtrlB.self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }
}

class CtrlB: UIViewController {
    static func badge (notification: NSNotification) {
        // blah blah
    }
}
```

Whats the correct way to unregister the notification listener above?
I'm not certain this is correct: 

`NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(CtrlB.self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)`

I don't think I can use `self` either, since it was registered on `CtrlB.self`

Comment: You can use just `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` and it will remove all observer in the currently class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the best way to implement the notification in your project is create one class called `NotificationManager` inside that declare one dictionary in which you can always update the observers

```
class NotificationManager {
var observers = [String: AnyObject]()
}
```

> Create addObserver method, post notification method and remove
>   observer method inside the same class.

```
func postNotification(_ name: String, userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]? = nil) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

func addObserver(_ name: String, block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
 //if observer is already in place for this name, remove it
  removeObserverForName(name)
  let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: block)
  self.observers[name] = observer
}

func removeObserver(_ name: name) {
 guard let observer = self.observers[name] else { return }
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
 self.observers.removeValue(forKey: name)
}

 //Removes all observers
func removeAllObservers() {
for observer in self.observers.values {
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
 }self.observers = [:]
}
```

> So access the above method in any of your class wherever its required and it will take care of everything. This will also prevent crash in your code. If try to remove the same observer more than one time.

Comment: I use a notification manager myself.  It is very nice since it will properly clean up everything when it is deallocs.  Though I use an array of NSObjectProtocol to store the observers.

Comment: from this line `guard let observer = self.observers[name] else { return }`
I suppose you meant this instead:
`guard let observer = self.observerDict[name] else { return }`
right? @Hussain

Comment: Yes Right, Corrected though

Comment: One more thing, how would you generally use this? I imagine you have to create an instance in any class you want to use it, which would mean each instance would have a different dictionary of observers, is that ok?
If the observer dictionary were static as well as the functions, would that not work better?

Comment: In our project we created instance of any class wherever it was required. But it depends on your requirement how you can manage.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are registering/unregistering to notifications with a class and not an instance. 'CtrlB.self' - will not give you an instance of the CtrlB class, in fact it will return a class itself.
Instead you should use something like this:

```
class CtrlA {

    let ctrlBInstance = CtrlB()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(ctrlBInstance, selector: #selector(CtrlB.badge(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(ctrlBInstance, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

And your ClassB should look like this in this case:

```
class CtrlB {
   func badge (notification: NSNotification) {
        // blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: The instantiating of controller without pointing to nib/storyboard viewController with identifier would cause crash. Also Instantiating variables on the class level is not recommended.

Comment: @DominikBucher it will not cause a crash. About variables on the class level you are right (sort of), but this is a general example of how to register/unregister correctly, so i guess how i declared that constant is not that important.

Comment: okay then how the constant knows which nib to use and properly assogns the iboutlets?

Comment: @DominikBucher UIViewController can have no nib and no IBOutlets associated with it. That's why there is a constructor with no parameters in the UIViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the instance of the observer,which you haven't declared...

for instance you need to set class variable secondA...

```
class CtrlA: UIViewController {

var secondController: CtrlB?


override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

    if let unwrappedController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as? CtrlB
    {
    secondController = unwrappedController        
    }

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let secondController = secondController
    {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(CtrlB.self, selector: #selector(CtrlB.badge(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let secondController = secondController
    {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(CtrlB.self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }
}

//Also don't forget to remove listening on deinit

deinit
{
    if let secondController = secondController
    {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(secondController, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "badge"), object: nil)
    }
  }
}

    class CtrlB: UIViewController {
        //Here you go with notification...
        static func badge (notification: NSNotification) {
            // blah blah
        }
    }
```